# How to stop my push to be merged with my open PR?

Tags: github

I have opened a PR which is still open and not merged yet, But I have worked on something else and want to create new PR for that. but whenever I push my changes, they are getting mixed with my last open PR. actually I don't want that to happen. I want my changes to not be merged with my open PR.
instead I want to create another PR for that.

Comment: Note that PRs (or MRs) are specific to each hosting site, not generic across Git itself (which does not have PRs/MRs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple PRs open from a single branch. To make a separate PR you need another branch (or another fork).